# Convergence of double summation of divergent and convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I am looking at two series

(a)$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2 (n + 1)^{2p}}\sum_{m = 1}^n (m + 1)^{2p}$$

and

(b)
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(n + 1)^{2p}}\sum_{m = 1}^n \dfrac{(m + 1)^{2p}}{m^2}$$

Assume $p \in (0, 1]$ for both (a) and (b). I wish to figure out which of the ones is summable and not summable (and for which power this holds).

---

Suppose $p = 1$ for simplicity, then, the first few terms of (a) are:

$\dfrac{2^2}{2^2} + \dfrac{2^2 + 3^2}{2^2 3^2} + \dfrac{2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2}{3^2 4^2} + \ldots = 1 + \dfrac{1}{2^2} + \dfrac{1}{3^2} + \dfrac{1}{3^2 4} + \dfrac{1}{4^2} + \dfrac{1}{3^2} + \ldots$

Since this seems to converge at similar rate as $1/n^2$, does this indicate that (a) is convergent?

---

Similarly for (b), the first few terms are,

$\dfrac{2^2}{2^2} + \dfrac{2^2 + 3^2/2^2}{3^2} + \dfrac{2^2 + 3^2/2^2 + 4^2/3^2}{4^2} + \ldots =  1 + 2^2/3^2 + 1/2^2 + 1/4 + 3^2/4^3 + 1/3^2 + \ldots$

For this one I really have no idea what I could use to determine convergence.

Comment: For $p=1$, the inner sum has an easy closed form: $\frac16(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)-1$, hence the series is divergent: you are adding terms $\sim\dfrac{1}{3n}$. And the second series is divergent as well, as the terms are larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first series is divergent for all $p>0$, and therefore so is the second, whose terms are larger.

To see this, consider $\alpha>0$, and let's show that $\sum_{k=1}^nk^\alpha\sim Cn^{\alpha+1}$ for some constant $C$.

We have

$$\frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nk^\alpha=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^\alpha$$

This is a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), for the continuous function $f(x)=x^\alpha$, therefore

$$\frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nk^\alpha\to\int_0^1 x^\alpha\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{\alpha+1}$$

Hence

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^\alpha\sim\frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}$$

Hence the term in the first series is equivalent to $\dfrac{n^{2p+1}}{(2p+1)n^2n^{2p}}\sim\dfrac{1}{(2p+1)n}$, and the series is divergent, per the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

For the second series, just note that

$$\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{(m+1)^{2p}}{m^2}\ge\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{m=1}^n(m+1)^{2p}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed analysis. May I ask what does the tilde symbol mean? I see this a lot online but I don't know exactly what this means.

Comment: @EldacarHyarmendacil $f(x)\sim g(x)$ (as $x\to x_0$) if $f(x)=(1+\epsilon(x))g(x)$, where $\epsilon(x)\to0$, for $x\to x_0$. Or, if $g$ does not vanish, if $f(x)/g(x)\to1$. That is, $f$ and $g$ have a similar behavior. You can read it "$f(x)$ is equivalent to $g(x)$ as $x$ tends to $x_0$". Here, $x$ is often a real or an integer, and $x_0$ may be infinite. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis

Comment: @EldacarHyarmendacil Additionally, since you probably don't know it if you don't know about equivalents, the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) states that if $f(n)\sim g(n)$, $\sum_nf(n)$ converges iff $\sum_n g(n)$ converges. It's one of many [convergence tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests).